# Ghost USB driver reconnect randomly

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, lenovo-laptop

I'm using Lenovo Legion-Y530. I have a problem with a ghost USB device in port#4_Hub#1(I have 3 USB ports on my laptop). The device connects/disconnects randomly, sometimes every 20 seconds and sometimes every hour or more, and plays a sound which I plug/unplug a real USB device. I thought this is ESETs problem because when I clicked on driver details, it seems that this device is related to ESET: "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\edevmon.sys" which was for ESET, I uninstalled it and edevmon.sys removed but nothing changed, it doesn't show me driver details anymore.
What I've tried:

1. unplugged every external USB device
2. Disable USB power from power options.
3. Uninstall ESET
4. Tried safe mode
5. Remove USB driver
6. Update windows and drivers (if fact, No update available)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suddenly found that the USB-C port is causing this problem, When I connected my phone charger to the USB-C port, the Error fixed even after a restart.
For more information, Check [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-usb-c-problems-f4e0e529-74f5-cdae-3194-43743f30eed2) Website:

> Unfortunately, some combinations of hardware and software may cause problems. If this happens, you may get a notification that there’s something wrong with the USB-C connection.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your rather extensive measures, I can also suggest to update
the BIOS. I have found this
[Lenovo BIOS update page](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/fr/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/legion-series/legion-y530-15ich/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI),
but check well before starting that the computer model is the same as yours.

If in doubt, you may go to the
[Automatic Driver Update](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/fr/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/legion-series/legion-y530-15ich/downloads/automatic-driver-update)
that will scan your computer to suggest updates of all the drivers it finds.

If software update does not help, then the problem is hardware.
You may seek to repair the computer, or, if you have the possibility,
replace the USB ports card or condemn the bad port.

Comment: My BIOS is the latest version. I also tried Driver Update before. The problem still remains.

Comment: You have then done all that is possible in software. What is left is hardware. Either replace that port if possible, or disable the port and live without it, or bring the computer to a repair-shop. I don't see other options.